# Can anyone explain me this code in scala ?

Tags: scala

Can anyone explain me the Scala code written below?

```
 trait A extends B {
  self =>
  type S >: self.type <: A
  def instance: S = self
}
```

Comment: Sure you can find something like https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html

Answer (score 8):

The line 
    `self =>`
is a self type declaration, with no type, so in trait A, self is a synonym of this.

The line 
    `type S >: self.type <: A`
defines a type S with upper bound and lower bound to it.
So S must be a subtype of A and a supertype of type of self (which is a concrete type of A)

Then the line 
    `def instance: S = self`
defines a method without arguments, a kind of property named instance, which return this casted to S.

Finally, why this code, i don't know, i don't like this kind of code.